# Place to buy new tefillin

Tags: product-recommendation, tefilin

Could anyone recommend a place to buy new tefillin?  I would be open to buying online or I live in the New York area, so also would be open to a store in the area.

Comment: Google can quickly find you places that sell tefillin. If you have more specific criteria that you want fulfilled then please provide them and maybe someone here could help you narrow things down.

Comment: If you tell me a soecific area I can find you a sofer who sells tefillin.

Comment: I don’t necessarily have more specific criteria. Was just wondering if anyone had a positive experience with a purchase recently or new someone that did that they might want to recommend.  I live in westchester so I can get to Monsey area or Brooklyn or Manhattan or North Jersey pretty easily.

Comment: @Yosef Kay, judging how you worded your question, you might want to spend some time educating yourself on what to look out for when purchasing tefillin before buying anything. Buying tefillin is no less complicated than buying a new car, those who are clueless most likely will not get the best deal (financially and spiritually) and  in the worst case, can get "junk". Here is one link https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/ask-the-expert-buying-tefillin/ but better to do your own search or to find a rabbi or an expert who can explain how to proceed. You'll be happy that you did. Good luck